# I want to take it but I don't get results, Even with bs4 I couldn't

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
from requests import get

link = get("https://www.instagram.com").text
re = re.findall(r'\"csrf_token\":\"(.*)",\"viewer\"', link)

print(re)
```

Comment: Please provide more details and use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 1):

You forget about **slashes**

Change:

```
re = re.findall(r'"csrf_token":"(.*)","viewer"', link)
```

To this:

```
re = re.findall(r'\\"csrf_token\\":\\"(.*)\\",\\"viewer\\"', link)
```

My result:

```
['some_token_text']
```